# Units and measurement

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I read on the characteristics of units

(i) It should be easily understandable.

(ii) It should be changed with change in physical factors.

(iii) It should not change with place or time.

I want to know that why we require all these characteristics in units?
What is the importance of these all characteristics for a unit?

Comment: Things that vary are called variables...

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you wrote, I suspect the second item should be that units should **not** change with changes in physical factors. This was one of the issues with the prototype-based definition of the kilogram: Despite heroic efforts to isolate the kilogram prototype from the environment, it changed due to temporarily removals from that the protected environment.

Comment: In pure math, you can multiply numbers together to your heart's content, because pure math is theoretical.  However, physics models things in the real world, and a number needs a unit to have any meaning.  This means that the real world places constraints on how you apply equations to it.